# How to read boost variable with type std::vector<std::vector<boost:any>>?

Tags: c++, boost

In Qt creator, I can read a variable (variable in front of "held" in the screenshot) that I want to use in my code.
However I can't store it in a variable.

[image]

I've already tried to use this syntax, but it doesn't work :

```
int maVar = boost::any_cast<int>(_myCUBParam->m_ValueVect[0])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @mch. I'm feeling a bit stupid because it was just the missing second `[0]`...
When I spy `maVar` with `maVar = boost::any_cast<int>(_myCUBParam->m_ValueVect[0][0])` value is not displayed (`<optimized out>` is displayed instead).
But when I print maVar in a csv file in my case, value is correctly printed.

Thanks a lot for your help